# Whatsapp implicit intent not working

Tags: image, android-intent, sharing, implicit, whatsapp

I am trying to share image and text via whatsapp using implicit intent but I'm not able to share. I have searched the net but could not find any proper explanation. I have attached the code below.
... the code works without errors.but it dose not share content with whatsapp. i have searched all the places in google and on stackoverflow .but could not encounter with any proper explanation

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView title_text,text_description;
    ImageButton main_image;
    Button button;


    private static String url = "random url ";



    private static final String TAG_ID = "title";
    private static final String TAG_IMAGE = "image_url";
    private static final String TAG_DESC = "product_desc";

    String id;
    String name;
    String image;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text_description=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_description);
        title_text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_title);
        main_image=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.image_main);
        button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);


        new GetContacts().execute();
       }

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"whatsappsharing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent whatsappintent=new Intent();
        whatsappintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        Uri uri= Uri.parse(TAG_IMAGE);
        whatsappintent.setType("text/plain");
        whatsappintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "hello nathar");

        whatsappintent.setType("image/jpeg");
        whatsappintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
        whatsappintent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        startActivity(whatsappintent);

    }


    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

         @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();



        }

        @Override
         protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();


            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.POST);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

             if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                     JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);



                        id = jsonObj.getString(TAG_ID);
                    Log.d(TAG_ID,"title");


                        name = jsonObj.getString(TAG_DESC);
                    Log.d(TAG_DESC,"name");




                      image=jsonObj.getString(TAG_IMAGE);
                    Log.d(TAG_IMAGE,"image");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
          }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);



            if (image!=null && !image.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                      Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(image).fit().into(main_image);

        title_text.setText(id);
        text_description.setText(name);
         }

         }

         }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this piece of code:

```
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(TAG_IMAGE);
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        // Target whatsapp:
        shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        // Add text and then Image URI
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, <Message_text>);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        try {
            startActivity(shareIntent);
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

where **Message_text** will be sent as a image caption

Comment: Vaibhav Barad . Can you tell me how to intent the image url as whatsapp msg using my same code (above) as example\